# Error in eclipse, servlets

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

Here's some error im getting on Eclipse

```
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet
```

It says HttpServlet cannot be resolved to a type , pls help

Comment: You need to add servlet-api.jar into your classpath

Comment: Are you using Tomcat?

Comment: did you include `servlet-api.jar` in your class path ?

Comment: just add the servlet-api.jar file your classpath , its available inside tomcat/lib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check project build path whether Servlets api jar file is included or not. you can add it in two ways:

1) add servlets api .jar file to build path 
or
2) add server runtime (i add Tomcat server runtime library) in build path

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the runtime libraries from your application server.

For example:

Go to project properties.  Click Build Path, then the libraries tab.  Click add library, then select Server Runtime.  Select your server and click OK.

[image]

Comment: can you please tell me why you do this? What is the logic behind this, as I have set the classpath in enviroment variables for servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar why it not works?

Answer (score 0):

If your project is maven then add following dependancy :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

[Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0L9yTE_zFM0)

For gradle projects:

```
dependencies {
providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
}
```

or download `javax.servlet.jar` and add to your project.

Steps:

1. Right click on project.
2. Go To Properties.
3. Go to Java Build Path.
4. Select Add Library option from tabs.
5. Add Jar Files give path of your servlet-api.jar file.
6. Clean and build your project.